# Calculate step length using R

Tags: r, gps, geosphere

I would like to know if there's a specific function in R that calculates step length, as being the distance (in meters) between two consecutive GPS time-registered locations.

I have a dataset looking as follows:

```
> head(datagps)
   Date & Time [Local]  Latitude Longitude
1: 2018-06-18 03:01:00 -2.434901  34.85359
2: 2018-06-18 03:06:00 -2.434598  34.85387
3: 2018-06-18 03:08:00 -2.434726  34.85382
4: 2018-06-18 03:12:00 -2.434816  34.85371
5: 2018-06-18 03:16:00 -2.434613  34.85372
6: 2018-06-18 03:20:00 -2.434511  34.85376
```

And would like to create a column `Step` which would do such operation as mentionned above. Maybe `geosphere` package has such function? If not, what would be the most compact way to do this?

Any input is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `geosphere` and calculate the `distHaversine` between two coordinates:

```
library(geosphere)
distm(c(lon1, lat1), c(lon2, lat2), fun = distHaversine)
```

Use `mutate` to add the `Step` field

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When using distm() how can I specify the c() arguments according to my syntax in the post? I'm using the following but I'm rather new to R so I'm totally unsure: `> datagps$Step<-distm(c(datagps$Longitude, datagps$Latitude), c(datagps$Longitude+1, datagps$Latitude+1), fun = distHaversine)
Error in .pointsToMatrix(x) : Wrong length for a vector, should be 2`

Answer (score 3):

I vectorized the Haversine function found at https://github.com/michaelmalick/r-malick/blob/master/R/haversine.R

```
haversine <- function(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2, r = 6378137) {

    if(!is.numeric(c(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2)))
        stop("Inputs are not numeric")

    # Convert degrees to radians
    lon1 <- lon1 * pi / 180
    lat1 <- lat1 * pi / 180
    lon2 <- lon2 * pi / 180
    lat2 <- lat2 * pi / 180

    delta.lon <- (lon2 - lon1)
    delta.lat <- (lat2 - lat1)
    a <- sin(delta.lat/2)^2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) *
         sin(delta.lon/2)^2
    c <- 2 * asin(min(1,sqrt(a)))
    d <- r * c

    return(d) # Distance
}

vectorized_haversine <- Vectorize(haversine, vectorize.args = c("lon1", "lat1", "lon2", "lat2"))
```

Next, I used the dplyr functions 'lag' and 'mutate', along with the vectorized haversine function to get the distances between consecutive points (the function 'tribble' was used to recreate `head(datagps)`).

```
library(dplyr)
 tribble(
      ~`Date & Time [Local]`, ~Latitude, ~Longitude,
       "2018-06-18 03:000", -2.434901,    34.85359,
       "2018-06-18 03:06:00", -2.434598,  34.85387,
      "2018-06-18 03:08:00", -2.434726,  34.85382,
       "2018-06-18 03:12:00", -2.434816,  34.85371,
      "2018-06-18 03:16:00", -2.434613,  34.85372,
       "2018-06-18 03:20:00", -2.434511,  34.85376
    ) %>% 
      mutate(Step = 
               vectorized_haversine(Longitude, Latitude, lag(Longitude), lag(Latitude)))


  Date & Time [Local]  Latitude Longitude     Step
1   2018-06-18 03:000 -2.434901  34.85359       NA
2 2018-06-18 03:06:00 -2.434598  34.85387 45.90731
3 2018-06-18 03:08:00 -2.434726  34.85382 15.29559
4 2018-06-18 03:12:00 -2.434816  34.85371 15.81292
5 2018-06-18 03:16:00 -2.434613  34.85372 22.62521
6 2018-06-18 03:20:00 -2.434511  34.85376 12.19500
```

Comment: I've used your script but getting the following error:`> vectorized_haversine <- Vectorize(haversine, vectorize.args = c("lon1", "lat1", "lon2", "lat2"))
> mutate(datagps$Step = 
Error: unexpected '=' in "mutate(datagps$Step ="
>          vectorized_haversine(datagps$Longitude, datagps$Latitude, lag(datagps$Longitude), lag(datagps$Latitude)))
Error: unexpected ')' in "         vectorized_haversine(datagps$Longitude, datagps$Latitude, lag(datagps$Longitude), lag(datagps$Latitude)))"` Am I writing the script in a bad syntax or is there something else?

Comment: I'm not totally sure. The code I posted works for me. Did you change `Step = ` to `datagps$Step = ` inside of the mutate function? If so, just use `Step =`.

Try:
`datagps_with_steps <- datagps %>% mutate(Step = 
               vectorized_haversine(Longitude, Latitude, lag(Longitude), lag(Latitude)))`

Answer (score 2):

Check out: **gmapdistance**

Note: A string or vector of strings containing the description of the starting point(s). Should be inside of quoutes (""). If more than one word for the same location is used, they should be separated by a plus sign e.g. "Bogota+Colombia". ***Coordinates in LAT-LONG format are also a valid input as long as they can be identified by Google Maps.***

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gmapsdistance/gmapsdistance.pdf

The function gmapsdistance uses the Google Maps Distance Matrix API in order to compute the distance(s) and time(s) between two points. In order to be able to use the function, you will need an API key and enable the Distance Matrix API in the Google Developers Console

### Caveat:

Note that Google has changed its billing practices. (Joy)

*You must have a valid API key and a billing account to access our APIs. When you enable billing, you will get $200 free usage every month for Maps, Routes, or Places. Based on the millions of users using our APIs today, most of them can continue to use Google Maps Platform for free with this credit. Having a billing account helps us understand our developers’ needs better and allows you to scale seamlessly.*

For more information about how to get a key, go to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/get-api-key#key

For more information about the Google Maps Distance Matrix API go to
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro?hl=en

#### Example:

A list with the traveling time(s) and distance(s) between origin(s) and destination(s) and the status

```
results = gmapsdistance(origin = "38.1621328+24.0029257", 
                        destination = "37.9908372+23.7383394",
                        mode = "walking")
```